# Universal Windows Reference is pointing to wrong file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have a Windows Universal App in process being made in Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows 10 on a Windows 10 machine. The program is written entirely in VB.net and obviously XAML for the forms.

Yesterday, out of the blue, a whole bunch of errors came up which were mostly referring to `x:name's` in the `.vb` files where I was using the XAML objects names in the VB file for various things.  I traced the problem to the Universal Windows reference pointing to a different file then it should. It is pointing to some sort of VOIP Calling Reference, which is really besides the point.

I tried to add a reference path to the project using the correct folder but that did not work. I tried to delete the reference but the program will not allow me to because it says that reference is put in by the editor and can not be removed. I have confirmed that I have the correct files on my computer and other projects reference's work. I did a repair on Visual Studio hoping that would solve the problem, but it did not.

I am thinking the problem is with that particular project and am at the point where I will be forced to make a new project and import the various files into it and sort of start over with a fresh project solution. I'm just seeing if there is a better way to fix this situation.

All comments and help are appreciated.

**EDIT**:  Adding Screen Shots of Visual Studio for this Project >>

[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGih.jpg)

[Screen Shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDoX6.jpg)

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I suppose I can share the actual Visual Studio project, or perhaps a screenshot of the reference path?

Comment: So could you share the actual Visual Studio project and screenshot of the reference path?